# Merge [microsoft-entra-id] and [azure-active-directory]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Microsoft Azure Active Directory was renamed to Microsoft Entra ID. I propose the [azure-active-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-active-directory) and [microsoft-entra-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-entra-id) tags be merged, and [azure-active-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-active-directory) become a synonym of [microsoft-entra-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-entra-id).

- Announcement: [Microsoft Entra expands into Security Service Edge and Azure AD becomes Microsoft Entra ID](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2023/07/11/microsoft-entra-expands-into-security-service-edge-and-azure-ad-becomes-microsoft-entra-id/?culture=en-us&country=us)
- Naming guidance: [New name for Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/new-name)

Comment: There are also multiple other [Azure AD tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-ad*) so I would suggest that these get similar treatments (a rename with synonym seems more appropriate here, as only [[tag:microsoft-entra-id]] currently exists from a new tag perspective).